# Angular get data from http put

Tags: angular, api, rest, http

I'm tring to retrive data from an endpoint something like to put in some datatable:
-http://XXXXXX:8080/groups/get

-HTTP PUT

The response should be something like this:

```
[
 {"GroupId":"0002A",
  "description": "description test one", 
  "Name": "Test02", 
  "department": "dep02"}
 ,
 {"GroupId":"0001A",
  "description": "description test one", 
  "Name": "Test01", 
  "department": "dep01"}
   ,....]
```

DTO:

```
export interface DynamicGroup {
 dynamicGroupId: string;
 description: string;
 displayName: string;
 corp: string;
}
```

service.ts:

```
  getDynamicGroup() {
     return this.httpClient.put<DynamicGroup[]>('http://XXXXXX:8080/groups/get', null);
  }
```

component.ts:

```
 searchGroups() {
  this.userService.getDynamicGroup().subscribe(groups => {
  this.groups =groups. ???  <--- the groups should return the data from message above;
});
}
```

At this point , I believe that the problem is how I'm calling the endpoint on service.ts , but I'm new on angular and I don't know how to solve this issue to get the data from endpoint.

Comment: Why are you `GET`ting the data using empty `PUT` request?

Comment: @Antoniossss you mean the null param from body ?

Comment: 1) Put without body 2) getting data via put instead of get  - both are wrong (totally doable, but why?)

Comment: And you didnt show what actually is returned from the backend (if anything)

Comment: @PedroMendes anything in network tab or console.log

Comment: @NavnathJadhav 404 error(not found )  , server can´t find the response from frontend

Comment: @PedroMendes Make sure about endpoint details. Try hitting endpoint using Postman before using it in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The URL from backend was different from the one that was used on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

you should pass the data in `getDynamicGroup` instead of passing null

EG:

```
getDynamicGroup(data:DynamicGroup) {
     return this.httpClient.put<DynamicGroup>('http://XXXXXX:8080/groups/get', data);
  }
```

Comment: and how should i call it at component ?